# background color css not getting applied for ace:textEntry

Tags: css, primefaces, icefaces-3

I am using icefaces 3.2. I have a css issue with my input box. I have a textentry which is as follows

```
                <ace:textEntry id="custName" value="#{strformbean.customer1.custName}"   size="20" maxlength="50"  label="Customer Name"
                     required="true"  styleClass="requiredField" />

  <style type="text/css" >
    .requiredField{
        background: rgb(255,239,214) ;
        border-color:Gray   ;
    }
</style>
```

The styleClass="requiredField" is supposed to change the background color of hte textentry.But it is not getting applied. When i use the IE CSS Debugger, i notice that the actual html source which is as follows

```
<input name="form:custName_input" class="ui-inputfield ui-textentry ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-required requiredField" id="form:custName_input" role="textbox" aria-required="true" type="text" size="20" maxLength="50" jQuery17104644470378519651="44"/>
```

has lot of css rules applied for this input box before my css rule. And background style in my rule is shown as stroked out , meaning there is some other rule which is applying the background.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd suggest using a browser with better developer tools, if possible. Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox have excellent tools that give a greater level of detail on where styles originate from and what is being overridden. They also allow you to toggle, amend and add new styles on the fly.

In your case, given the number of other classes applied to the input field, it's highly likely that your class `.requiredField` is being overriden by a selector with a higher specificity. For example, the following rule:

```
.requiredField {
    color: rgb(255,239,214); 
}
```

would be overriden by this one:

```
.container .requiredField {
    color: black; 
}
```

There's a great article by Chris Coyier that explains this topic in greater detail: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Given your selector is probably being overridden, you have two options:

1. Give your selector higher specificity than the others (as above), for example: 
   `.container .requiredField { ... }`
2. Use `!important` to override all other styles applied to the element, e.g.
    `color: red !important;`. **Note:** I only suggest this as it suits the purpose of the style (validation). This should be used sparingly as it can lead to long-term maintenance issues with multiple overrides.

In both cases it's important to see exactly what other styles are being applied so that you can use the best solution. For example, it's not a good idea to arbitrarily add IDs and classes to a selector in order to override other styles as that leads to the same problem. I'd also suggest not putting styles inside the document using `<style>`. While it's perfectly valid, it makes it hard to keep track of CSS and is generally seen as bad practice. It's preferable to link to an external stylesheet using the `<link>` tag.